# How to make search bar not scrolling along with table view?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uisearchdisplaycontroller

I want to make a search bar like this.

[image]

The search bar in contacts app is stay while I scroll down. I want to make a search bar with this property that **It doesn't scroll down along with table view** . I did my app in table view controller.This is my code in my table view controller.

myTableViewController(in my viewDidLoad function):

```
searchController = UISearchController(searchResultsController: nil)
searchController.hidesNavigationBarDuringPresentation = false
searchController.searchBar.searchBarStyle = UISearchBarStyle.Prominent
searchController.searchBar.sizeToFit()
tableView.tableHeaderView = searchController.searchBar
definesPresentationContext = true
searchController.searchResultsUpdater = self
searchController.dimsBackgroundDuringPresentation = false
```

It should work like search bar in contact because of this code

```
tableView.tableHeaderView = searchController.searchBar
```

Is there something i do wrong? If not then how to make my search bar doesn't scroll down with table view(in table view controller)?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of a search bar *in* a table view, make a search bar *and* a table view. Thus, the search bar just sits there while the table view scrolls.

Comment: I have tried using view controller and it produce an error sigbrt. If I make it seperately how table can have a result of a search bar? @matt

Comment: That's completely irrelevant. The result table is a completely different table. Setting up the result table through the UISearchController's `searchResultsController` is up to you. (Your mistake, as shown in the above code, is that you are setting the `searchResultsController` as `nil`.) But anyway, that isn't what you asked. What you asked is how to show the _original_ interface, as in Contacts, with the search bar separate from the table. And I answered that.